# How to fix a missing template error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, validation

I am making a website that has a user page that is supposed to allow users to create announcement posts.

When I try to create a new announcement post through the website, an error pops up as follows:

```
Template is missing
Missing template announcements/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en],     :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * ".../app/views"
```

If I create the create.html.erb at the location, the form will return false as always.

The user page (/app/view/users/show.html.erb):

```
<% provide(:title, 'Admin Page') %>

<% if signed_in? %>
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
    <br />

     <% if @announcements.any? %>
      <h3>Announcements (<%= @announcements.count %>)</h3>
      <ol>
        <%= render @announcements %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate @announcements %>
    <% end %>

      <%= render 'shared/announcement_form' %>
  </div>

<% else %>
<script type="text/javascript"> window.location.href= '<%= signin_path %>' </script>
<% end %>
```

shared/_announcement_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@announcement) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

   <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :title, placeholder: "Compose new title..." %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new announcement..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

UsersController:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @announcement = current_user.announcements.build if signed_in?
    @announcements = @user.announcements.paginate(:page => params[:a_page], :per_page  => 10)
  end
end
```

AnnouncementsController:

```
class AnnouncementsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def create
    @announcement = current_user.announcements.build(announcement_params)

    if @announcement.save
      flash[:success] = "Announcement created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:error] = "Failed to create announcement!"
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

  def announcement_params
    params.require(:announcement).permit(:content)
    params.require(:announcement).permit(:title)
  end
end
```

I have checked that I can create the announcement manually in the console. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `@announcement` fails to save in `AnnouncementsController#create`, you render the default view for the action - in this case `create.html.erb` which doesn't exist. Thus, you get the error you're seeing.

Usually, the create action would re-render the template with the form. Usually that's the `new` action, which would mean adding `render "new"` to the `else` part of your `create` action.

In your case however, it seems like it's in the `"shared/announcements_form"` partial, which would mean adding

```
render "shared/announcements_form"
```

to your `create` action.

Comment: Thanks, although putting render "shared/_announcements_form" still create the same "Template error", but i get the idea.

I add "redirect_to :back" and it works better, as _announcements_form.html.erb is a partial of users/show.html.erb, and somehow render or redirect_to "users/show" would cause another error.

Also, the reason of announcement failed to save, is that announcement_params should be in one line, params.require(:announcement).permit(:title, :content), not separated into two.

Answer (score 1):

Putting a `redirect_to` or `render "shared/announcements_form"` in that `else` block like you're doing when the announcement is successfully saved will solve the problem.

The announcement you're trying to create fails to save, so the `else` block is executed and this is what tries to render `announcements/create.html.erb`. By convention, if there isn't any explicit `render` in an action, Rails tries to renders whatever view corresponds to that action.

Answer (score 0):

Check your path, make sure your full path is spelled correctly (i.e folders) not just the file name.  After fixing my typo in the folder name, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this here in case someone else has the same issue.

I kept having the error `ActionView::MissingTemplate` using **Rails 7**, **Windows 11** and **Git Bash**. Starting the Rails server with **Git Bash** threw the `Missing Template` bug all the time, as if Rails was ignoring my files. However, launching the server with the **Windows Command Prompt** worked perfectly fine, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63104581/12099013).

I stumbled upon this [link](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18660#issuecomment-73009706) which provided me the answer. One of the directories in my root path was capitalized as follows: `path/to/FOO`.

Renaming my folder to `foo` did not work straight away. I had to rename it first to a different name such as `blablabla` then back to `foo`. Thus the full path is `path/to/foo`. This finally allowed me to start the server with Git Bash.

I later found this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27871726/strange-error-in-rails-missing-helper/27909917#27909917) which also deals with this problem. I am adding it here for additional documentation.