# ruby on rails AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError: Missing helper file helpers//

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.2

I just cloned a repository I was working on from another computer.  When I try to do a database migration by running 'rake db:migrate' I get the following error:

```
AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError: 
Missing helper file helpers//users/psmith/projects/clie/projectlion/app/helpers/application_helper.rb_helper.rb
```

I have already tried the top answer here: [Rails: AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError - Missing helper file application_helper.rb_helper.rb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884908/rails-abstractcontrollerhelpersmissinghelpererror-missing-helper-file-app)

It says to do the following in the terminal:

```
cd ~
mv projects projects1
mv projects1 projects
```

I have also tried:

```
sudo ln -s Users users
```

But this does not work for me.  What should I do?

UPDATE:

Here is my stacktrace:

```
ps-MacBook-Pro:projectlion psmith$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError: Missing helper file helpers//users/psmith/projects/clie/projectlion/app/helpers/application_helper.rb_helper.rb
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:154:in `rescue in block in modules_for_helpers'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:151:in `block in modules_for_helpers'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:147:in `map!'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:147:in `modules_for_helpers'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb:93:in `modules_for_helpers'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:111:in `helper'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/railties/helpers.rb:17:in `inherited'
/Users/psmith/projects/clie/projectlion/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `block in load_file'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:633:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:442:in `load_file'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:480:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `const_get'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `block in constantize'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `each'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `inject'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `constantize'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/devise-fea2b95c5fde/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `block in load_file'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:633:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:442:in `load_file'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:480:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/devise-fea2b95c5fde/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `block in load_file'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:633:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:442:in `load_file'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:480:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-3f916d6bee73/lib/active_admin/devise.rb:55:in `<module:Devise>'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-3f916d6bee73/lib/active_admin/devise.rb:6:in `<module:ActiveAdmin>'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-3f916d6bee73/lib/active_admin/devise.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/psmith/projects/clie/projectlion/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:337:in `instance_exec'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:337:in `eval_block'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:315:in `draw'
/Users/psmith/projects/clie/projectlion/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:71:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
/Users/psmith/projects/clie/projectlion/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:379:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
LoadError: No such file to load -- /users/psmith/projects/clie/projectlion/app/helpers/application_helper.rb_helper
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `block in load_file'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:633:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:442:in `load_file'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:307:in `depend_on'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:152:in `block in modules_for_helpers'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:147:in `map!'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:147:in `modules_for_helpers'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb:93:in `modules_for_helpers'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:111:in `helper'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/railties/helpers.rb:17:in `inherited'
/Users/psmith/projects/clie/projectlion/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `block in load_file'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:633:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:442:in `load_file'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:480:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `const_get'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `block in constantize'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `each'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `inject'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `constantize'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/devise-fea2b95c5fde/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `block in load_file'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:633:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:442:in `load_file'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:480:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/devise-fea2b95c5fde/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `block in load_file'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:633:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:442:in `load_file'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:480:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-3f916d6bee73/lib/active_admin/devise.rb:55:in `<module:Devise>'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-3f916d6bee73/lib/active_admin/devise.rb:6:in `<module:ActiveAdmin>'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-3f916d6bee73/lib/active_admin/devise.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/psmith/projects/clie/projectlion/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:337:in `instance_exec'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:337:in `eval_block'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:315:in `draw'
/Users/psmith/projects/clie/projectlion/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:71:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
/Users/psmith/projects/clie/projectlion/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:379:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/psmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Does that file actually exist?  What do you get when you type 'ls /users/philipgreenwald/projects/callie/projectlion/app/helpers/application_helper.rb_helper.rb'?   Is the helper file in you app/helpers/ directory really named 'application_helper_rb.rb_helper.rb', or is it just 'application_helper.rb'?

Comment: The file does not exist.  It's just application_helper.rb.

Comment: Per the link you provided, have you searched for a "helpers" command like this 'helper "application_helper.rb"' in your controllers or anywhere else in your app?  This is almost certainly the cause of your problem.  When I put that in one of my test app controllers, I get the exact same error.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you're saying to search for?  There is definitely a file called application_helper.rb, as that is present in all rails apps.

Comment: Can you post the full error stacktrace?

Comment: In one of your controllers (or perhaps somewhere else in your app), there is probably a line that reads, "helper 'application_helper.rb'".  Instead, it should just say 'helper :application'.  If I put the former in one of my own test application controllers, I get your error message verbatim.  Check for this by looking through your controller files, or go to your application root directory and type 'git grep application_helper .' and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks, I tried doing that but it didnt work.  typing 'git grep application_helper .' into the terminal returned nothing.  I manually checked all the controllers and searched them with the finder and there is no mention of application_helper, other than the application_helper.rb file.

Comment: Then I think you've got to go with the stacktrace @dgilperez suggested.

Comment: BTW, are you on OSX?

Comment: I added the stacktrace.  Also, I am using OSX.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same challenge and after reading all of the answers and finding no success. This is how I fixed the error:

Open Finder and checked the path to my code. My path was `myMac/Code/my apps`.

I changed the `Code` to `code` and that fixed the error.

Now my path is `myMac/code/my apps`.

Comment: I actually just solved the issue yesterday, and you're exactly right!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem starting yesterday, and I just fixed it. The error started for me after I installed the command line tools for Xcode 6.3, and reverting back to command line tools for Xcode 6.2 resolved the issue. Here's where you can download the DMG for the previous version: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

It seems to be some sort of conflict between Ruby 2.2.* and Xcode 6.3 command line tools - hopefully it'll get fixed properly soon!

Answer (score 1):

I have this same issue. When I run `rake test`.
As suggested in this [Strange error in rails - missing helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27871726/strange-error-in-rails-missing-helper).
Try this in irb or pry:

```
pry(main)> File.expand_path('./')
```

You will get something like this `=> "/users/xxxx/Sites/xxxx"`

Then run `pwd` in your terminal and compare the path difference.
You will get something like this `/users/xxxx/sites/xxxx`.
If this is the case, the above method you tried will work. It due to possible ruby 2.2.0 or rails core issue where it messes up and capitalize the site name. So in a case sensitive OS like linux or mac, it won't find the path.

But if this is not the case for you, just like me. I suggest you check what version of ruby you are using. I was using `ruby 2.2.0`, then switch `2.2.1`. And `rails 4.2.0`.

Then I switch to `ruby 2.1.5`. rails version stays. Problem was solved. My guess is that was a problem with ruby?..

Answer (score 1):

in my case i was using windows. Using Git shell, i kept getting this error while trying to install the gem administrate from thoughtbot. The command that kept giving me the error,"AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError", was:

$ rails generate administrate:install

I did not rename my folder's to lowercase as many answers have suggested. I instead used the window's cmd. It worked perfectly.

Comment: I am new to rails, I did as such in the tutorial I was seeing but got this error. Your suggestion works perfectly tried rails server from cmd instead of Git Shell and now I don't see this error. Any Idea why such error is thrown?

Comment: @suryakrish , am not sure, but i guess when using the windows cmd, it uses the folders name as it is, so if you use a lowecase it will capitalize automatically if the folder/path name is in uppercase, unlike in the git shell, it uses the path name as you have given it.