# Michael Hartl RoR tutorial chapter 3, 2 errors with testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been stuck on this for near 4 hours now. In the chapter we are asked to run tests for the first time. It is outputting two errors, and I don't understand what they are.

These are the errors:

```
Finished in 0.097197s, 20.5768 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.



1) Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_help:
AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError: Missing helper file helpers//users/kevinmulhern/documents/the_odin_project/ruby_on_rails/sample_app/app/helpers/application_helper.rb_helper.rb
    app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'


  2) Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_home:
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template static_pages/home, application/home with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/kevinmulhern/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates"
  * "/Users/kevinmulhern/documents/the_odin_project/ruby_on_rails/sample_app/app/views"
  * "/Users/kevinmulhern/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/views"

    test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'

2 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 2 errors, 0 skips
```

I ended up scraping the app as I wasnt that far through it anyway and copy and pasted my way back to the section I got stuck at, I dont think it could be a typo causing this.

heres the controller for the StaticPages

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end
end
```

and finally here is the test file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get home" do
    get :home
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get :help
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

**updated error after deleting the helpers:**

```
1) Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_home:
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template static_pages/home, application/home with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/kevinmulhern/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates"
  * "/Users/kevinmulhern/documents/the_odin_project/ruby_on_rails/sample_app/app/views"
  * "/Users/kevinmulhern/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/views"

    test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>
```

**update**

I moved the project to my home directory, and that solved the problem. There must have been something wrong with my directory structure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails: AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError - Missing helper file application\_helper.rb\_helper.rb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884908/rails-abstractcontrollerhelpersmissinghelpererror-missing-helper-file-app)

Answer (score 0):

For your first error, without looking at any code or anything else I can tell you that this: `//users/kevinmulhern/documents/the_odin_project/ruby_on_rails/sample_app/app/helpers/application_helper.rb_helper.rb` smells bad (notice the two `.rb` occurrences in the `application_helper.rb_helper.rb` part) **update:** Check [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884908/rails-abstractcontrollerhelpersmissinghelpererror-missing-helper-file-app).

For the second one, your error message is this: `ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template static_pages/home`. Have a look around for what `missing template` means. *(hint: do you have a `static_pages/home.html.erb` file?)*

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, I changed the application helper file name to application_helper.rb but that hasn't fixed it unfortunately. Yeah the static_pages/home.html.erb file is there.

Comment: Can you update the question with the new error message you are getting for application_helper?

Comment: I took out both the applicatio_helper and the static_pages_helper and now its showing another template error. Ill add the error to the post.