# Why are Rails tests not working properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

Attempting to do the Rails tutorial on railstutorial.org. I'm currently at the testing portion of the tutorial and I keep on getting an error when performing the test. The test file I created with 'generate StaticPages controller' command is as is, I have not modified it at all. When I enter in the command 'rails test' I get this error:

```
>/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:152:in `rescue in block in modules_for_helpers': Missing helper file helpers//users/user/programming/odin/rails/sample_app/app/helpers/application_helper.rb_helper.rb (AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError)
```

Here is the trace back:

```
>   from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:149:in `block in modules_for_helpers'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:145:in `map!'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:145:in `modules_for_helpers'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb:93:in `modules_for_helpers'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:109:in `helper'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_controller/railties/helpers.rb:17:in `inherited'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.0.1/lib/action_view/test_case.rb:11:in `<class:TestCase>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.0.1/lib/action_view/test_case.rb:10:in `<module:ActionView>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.0.1/lib/action_view/test_case.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rails-controller-testing-0.1.1/lib/rails-controller-testing.rb:16:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.0.1/lib/action_view/base.rb:215:in `<class:Base>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.0.1/lib/action_view/base.rb:139:in `<module:ActionView>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.0.1/lib/action_view/base.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/default_middleware_stack.rb:48:in `block in build_stack'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/default_middleware_stack.rb:13:in `tap'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/default_middleware_stack.rb:13:in `build_stack'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:504:in `default_middleware_stack'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:506:in `block in app'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:504:in `synchronize'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:504:in `app'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:37:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/user/Programming/Odin/rails/sample_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

If this is formatted and asked imporperly or what not I apologize, any help will be greatly appreciated I absolutely stumped.
Here is the github repo : https://github.com/JDjedi/sample_app

Rails version is 5.0 and ruby version is 2.3.0p0

Answer (score 0):

`application_helper.rb_helper.rb` - is this how you called your helper? `.rb` is an extension. Thus could you change the name of the helper file to `application_helper.rb` and see if that works?

Edit:

Did you look at this question? [Rails: AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError - Missing helper file application_helper.rb_helper.rb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884908/rails-abstractcontrollerhelpersmissinghelpererror-missing-helper-file-app)

Here seems to be a working answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28269245/1010826

Simply rename the root folder to the same name. Not sure why that would work, though :)

Comment: In the directory it is written as 'application_helper.rb'. I'll provide an extension to the github repo in the original post.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but I still do not understand