# AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm working on a web app using ruby on rails. When I tried to open up my web app, I run into an error whenever I try to load up my web app in localhost. I get error saying that the app is missing a helper file. I've looked at every solution and nothing has worked so far. Hopefully someone else can shed some light on the situation

**This is the full error message I'm getting**

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-06 17:06:17 -0700

AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError (Missing helper file helpers/c:/users/kendrickod/app_data/local/google/cloud sdk/art_walk/app/helpers/application_helper.rb_helper.rb):

app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/main_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
Error during failsafe response: Missing helper file helpers/c:/users/kendrickod/app_data/local/google/cloud sdk/art_walk/app/helpers/application_helper.rb_helper.rb
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:152:in `rescue in block in modules_for_helpers'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:149:in `block in modules_for_helpers'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:145:in `map!'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:145:in `modules_for_helpers'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb:93:in `modules_for_helpers'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:109:in `helper'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_controller/railties/helpers.rb:17:in `inherited'
  C:/Users/Kendrickod/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/ArtwAlk/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:476:in `load'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:476:in `block in load_file'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:661:in `new_constants_in'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:475:in `load_file'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:374:in `block in require_or_load'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:36:in `block in load_interlock'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:149:in `exclusive'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:36:in `load_interlock'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:357:in `require_or_load'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `load_missing_constant'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:202:in `const_missing'
  C:/Users/Kendrickod/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/ArtwAlk/app/controllers/main_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:476:in `load'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:476:in `block in load_file'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:661:in `new_constants_in'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:475:in `load_file'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:374:in `block in require_or_load'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:36:in `block in load_interlock'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:149:in `exclusive'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:36:in `load_interlock'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:357:in `require_or_load'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `load_missing_constant'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:202:in `const_missing'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:269:in `const_get'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:269:in `block in constantize'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `each'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `inject'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `constantize'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:582:in `get'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:613:in `constantize'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:82:in `controller_class'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:97:in `binary_params_for?'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:88:in `set_binary_encoding'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:58:in `parameters'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_negotiation.rb:63:in `block in formats'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/request.rb:57:in `fetch'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/request.rb:57:in `fetch_header'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_negotiation.rb:61:in `formats'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/public_exceptions.rb:22:in `call'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:49:in `render_exception'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:34:in `rescue in call'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/server.rb:602:in `handle_request'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: It seems to be another kind of problem, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884908/rails-abstractcontrollerhelpersmissinghelpererror-missing-helper-file-app).

Comment: Would that solution still work even though I put my app folder in the google cloud sdk file path.