# Missing helper file application_helper.rb_helper.rb after newest updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode

Just updated to Xcode 7.0 and osx 10.10.5 now, I'm getting this application_helper.rb_helper.rb error when I run the test suite. I had this error before, and fixed it by updating the rails -v.
It's not the capitalization error others have had from before.
Tried rolling back to Xcode 6.4 -no help there.

Currently using ruby 2.2.2 and Rails 4.2.1.

Any help is very greatly appreciated.

On the local machine, when hitting the root,I get this error

```
`/Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:151:in `rescue in block in modules_for_helpers': Missing helper file helpers//users/ryan/turing/homework/2_module/idea_box/app/helpers/application_helper.rb_helper.rb (AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError)
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:148:in `block in modules_for_helpers'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:144:in `map!'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:144:in `modules_for_helpers'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb:93:in `modules_for_helpers'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:108:in `helper'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/railties/helpers.rb:17:in `inherited'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/test_case.rb:11:in `<class:TestCase>'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/test_case.rb:10:in `<module:ActionView>'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/test_case.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-rails-3.3.3/lib/rspec/rails/example/helper_example_group.rb:9:in `<module:HelperExampleGroup>'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-rails-3.3.3/lib/rspec/rails/example/helper_example_group.rb:6:in `<module:Rails>'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-rails-3.3.3/lib/rspec/rails/example/helper_example_group.rb:4:in `<module:RSpec>'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-rails-3.3.3/lib/rspec/rails/example/helper_example_group.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-rails-3.3.3/lib/rspec/rails/example.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-rails-3.3.3/lib/rspec/rails.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/ryan/Turing/homework/2module/idea_box/spec/rails_helper.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ryan/Turing/homework/2module/idea_box/spec/controllers/ideas_controller_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/ryan/Turing/homework/2module/idea_box/spec/controllers/ideas_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `load'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `each'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:102:in `setup'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in `run'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `invoke'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Ryans-MacBook-Air:idea_box ryan$`
```

Comment: Can you please add more info on error like error message you are getting and also line of code where you get it?

Comment: Any time the application is loaded, this is the error.

Comment: Can you verify if this path matches with your project directory path including case sensitivities? `/users/ryan/turing/homework/2_module/idea_box/app/helpers/`, I f some directory is not exactly named please change to lower case

Comment: I can verify that. Used File.expand_path and pwd. Thanks

Comment: your directory names are a case sensitive match of above path?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27871726/strange-error-in-rails-missing-helper

Comment: The names are a case sensitive match.

Comment: Can you lower your ruby version to 2.1? This is a problem with ruby 2.2

Comment: Zahid, thanks for the help. reinstalled rvm and ruby. Solves this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated rvm as well as ruby (2.2.2) and rails (4.2.1). Solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same sort of error message running on much later versions of rails and ruby. Turned out I had added a new directory to the helper directory and needed to restart spring for it to be picked up.