# Rails requiring helpers with rb_helper file extension

Tags: ruby, helper, ruby-on-rails-4.2

After upgrading all of my gems, I now receive following error:

```
LoadError at /
No such file to load -- /users/mohnstrudel/dropbox (Личный)/projekte/personal/mosflash/app/helpers/application_helper.rb_helper
```

The error seems rather obvious, because my helper looks like this - application_helper.rb, not application_helper.rb_helper

If I rename all my helpers extensions to rb_helper the next error I receive is: (the template is of course there and the whole app worked before the update)

```
Missing template store_front/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/mohnstrudel/Dropbox (Личный)/Projekte/personal/mosflash/app/views"
```

I stumbled upon this question - [Strange error in rails - missing helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27871726/strange-error-in-rails-missing-helper/27909917#27909917)

But renaming folders didn't help.

My file paths:

```
2.2.0 :001 > File.expand_path ("./")
 => "/Users/mohnstrudel/Dropbox (Личный)/Projekte/personal/mosflash" 

MBP-Anton:mosflash mohnstrudel$ pwd
/Users/mohnstrudel/Dropbox/Projekte/personal/mosflash
```

Is this a problem caused by Dropbox? I'm using a private account and a corporate one, this is why there are brackets. However using cd Dropbox/ or cd Dropbox (Personal)/ leads to same folder.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your question. Where am I supposed to have this line? I do have the file though if it's that what you mean.

Comment: Did you try to move your project to a folder with a simpler name (i.e. that doesn't contain any cyrillic or special symbols like `(` )? Try move your project to a home directory and check again.

Comment: @AlexeyShein it actually worked! Is it some temporary rails issue or do I have to move every project to some "simplier" path?

Comment: I am afraid it's a constant issue and quite often is not rails specific, there's a lot of code in the wild that doesn't expect special or extended unicode characters in the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to move your project to a folder with a simpler name (i.e. that doesn't contain any cyrillic or special symbols like `(` )?

Try moving your project to a home directory and check again.