# AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError: Missing helper file helpers

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I created a new proyect[sic] in rails:

```
$rails new my_app 
$rail server
```

and it works just fine, but when I try to add more stuff:

```
$rails generate scaffold post title:string body:string
$rails db:migrate
$rails server
```

then I receive this error:

```
AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError in PagesController#dashboard
Missing helper file helpers//users/jamesfend/sites/feedbackz/app/helpers/application_helper.rb_helper.rb

Extracted source (around line #1):
1 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base    
2 # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
3 # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
4 protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

Im in windows 10 working with Git Bash v:2.13, rails v:5.0.1 and ruby v:2.2.6, I tried to change the names to capitals letters; I tried:

```
cd ~
mv projects projects1
mv projects1 projects
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I think the file name application_helper.rb_helper.rb is causing the problem. It should have been application_helper.rb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange error in rails - missing helper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27871726/strange-error-in-rails-missing-helper)

Comment: when i look at the original file it actually says aplication_helper.rb but when the error shows up it add the _helper.rb

Comment: when i write Post.all in the rails console it says;   Post Load (3.4ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
#<ActiveRecord::Relation []> is that normal? because it suppose to say the elements inside post right?

Comment: It will only contain posts if the db contains posts.

Comment: Run this in irb: File.expand_path("./") Then run: pwd. What is the output you get from each of these?

Comment: Please read the description for a tag before applying it to your question. The [tag:git] tag is for questions about Git usage and workflows, not programming questions that happen to involve a Git repo. (I've [edited](//stackoverflow.com/help/editing) your question to remove it.)

Comment: oh sorry Scott Weldon, thank you for changing it

Comment: when i write in the irb the File.expand_path("./") i get the route for my ruby version, is that what im looking for or i should change it some how?

Answer (score 1):

i finally know what happend, it was really simple. i just update all the ruby gems doing `gem update`and now it works. there was one gem (rdoc) that i couldnt update but it still worked