# How to fix PagesController#home is missing a template for request formats: text/html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

For my rails 6 application in my `routes.rb`, I have

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#home'
end
```

and in my `pages_controller.rb`, I have

```rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end
end
```

and I have `views/pages/home.html.erb` created.

However, when I start my rails server, I still get

```sh
PagesController#home is missing a template for request formats: text/html.
```

How do I solve this?

Edit:

It works if I do

```rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    render file: './app/views/pages/home.html.erb'
  end
end
```

but I don't think I am supposed to do this.

Comment: Please post code (not links to images of code) in your question. Use the formatting tools in SO's text editor to format it as code.

Comment: Post your controller code: you've either missed the format respond_to html block, or need to restart the server.

Comment: I have edited my question, and hopefully its a little more clear now. Thanks!

Comment: This question definitely falls in the "cannot reproduce" category and if you try creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the issue will most likely disappear on its own as its most likely a small typografical error or some other inconsistency. You can generate the controller and a view in the correct path with `rails g controller pages#home`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is resolved when I started the server using the windows command prompt rather than windows powershell